# How to download and check a sub-div with BeautifoulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get hands on some tickets for the Collosseum in Rome in a few weeks. But the Full Experience Tickets are always sold out!

So I thought about tracking the website and check if there is availability for tickets -> send me a message if new tickets are available.

As tool of choice I want to use Python with the BeautifullSoup and Requests libraries to download the sourcecode of the website and check if the background of the desired day changed color to green. (I try it this way, because I can't find the source where the website knows from if tickets are available in the sourcecode)

so this is the website:https://ecm.coopculture.it/index.php?option=com_snapp&view=event&id=D7E12B2E-46C4-074B-5FC5-016ED579426D&catalogid=DDDA3AB3-47BC-0A49-7752-0174490F632A&lang=en

and here's my Python code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

URL = 'https://ecm.coopculture.it/index.php?option=com_snapp&view=event&id=D7E12B2E-46C4-074B-5FC5-016ED579426D&catalogid=DDDA3AB3-47BC-0A49-7752-0174490F632A&lang=en'

#set the headers as a browser
headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'
}
#download the homepage
response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers) 

#parse the downloaded homepage and grab all text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html")

msg = soup

print(msg)
```

It should print me the whole sourcecode but it doesn't (oh wonder that's why I'm here :)

**The Information I'm looking for is hidden in the  but the printed sourcecode doesn't show the contents of the div. **

Where did i make a mistake?

Comment: The site probably uses JS to fill that content. You'll need a tool like selenium to scrape that.